# How to fix Flutter layout issues?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having issues with the layout and don't really know how to fix it. I would be happy to get a hint based in the following code.

big_text.dart file:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/utils/dimensions.dart';


    class BigText extends StatelessWidget {
      final Color? color; //The question mark makes it optional
      final String text;
      final double size;
      final TextOverflow overFlow;

      //final double size;
      //final TextOverflow overflow; // Corrected the typo in the property name


      BigText({Key? key, this.color = const Color(0xFF332D2B),
        required this.text,
        this.size=0,
        this.overFlow = TextOverflow.ellipsis
      }): super(key: key);       // Three dots called ellipses if there is a text overflow

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text(
          text,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: overFlow,
          style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: color,
        fontSize: size==0?Dimensions.font20:size,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

The second python file is called "food_page_body.dart".

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/controllers/popular_product_controller.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/utils/dimensions.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/widgets/app_column.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/widgets/big_text.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/widgets/icon_and_text_widget.dart';
    import 'package:my_app/widgets/small_text.dart';
    import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart';

    class FoodPageBody extends StatefulWidget {
      const FoodPageBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _FoodPageBodyState createState() => _FoodPageBodyState();
    }

    class _FoodPageBodyState extends State<FoodPageBody> {
      PageController pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85); 
      var _currPageValue=0.0;
      double _scaleFactor=0.8;
      double _height=Dimensions.pageViewContainer;

      @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        pageController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
        _currPageValue=pageController.page!; //Get the value of the page
        // print("Current Value is"+_currPageValue.toString());
          });
        });
      }

      // Remove the page from memory
      @override
      void dispose(){
        pageController.dispose();
      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
        //slider section - // Create an instance of the get builder
        GetBuilder<PopularProductController>(builder:(popularProducts){
          return Container(
          //color: Colors.redAccent, // Background color
            height: Dimensions.pageView,
            child: PageView.builder(
                controller: pageController,
                itemCount: popularProducts.popularProductList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return _buildPageItem(position);
                }),
          );
        }),

        //dots
        GetBuilder<PopularProductController>(builder: (popularProducts){
          return  DotsIndicator(
            dotsCount: popularProducts.popularProductList.isNotEmpty ? popularProducts.popularProductList.length: 2,
            //dotsCount: popularProducts.popularProductList.length,
            //dotsCount: 5,
            position: _currPageValue,
            decorator: DotsDecorator(
              activeColor: Color(0xFF80CBC4),
              size: const Size.square(9.0),
              activeSize: const Size(18.0, 9.0),
              activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            ),
          );
        }),

        //popular text
        SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height30,),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimensions.width30),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              BigText(text: "Popular"),
              SizedBox(width: Dimensions.width10,),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                child: BigText(text: ".", color:Colors.black26),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: Dimensions.width10,),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: SmallText(text: "Food pairing",),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

        //list of food and images
        ListView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true, //AlwaysScrollable..() oldugu zaman comment out yap
            itemCount:10, 
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimensions.width20, right: Dimensions.width20, bottom: Dimensions.height10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  //Image section
                  Container(
                    width: Dimensions.listViewImgSize,
                    height: Dimensions.listViewImgSize,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                      color: Colors.white38,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: AssetImage("lib/assets/image/sushi.jpg")
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                 
                  //text container
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: Dimensions.listViewTextContSize,
                      //width: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(Dimensions.radius20)
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimensions.width10, right: Dimensions.width10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, //vertical
                          children: [
                            BigText(text: "Nutritious fruit meal in Japan"),
                            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10,),
                            SmallText(text: "With japanese characteristics"),
                            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10,),

                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                IconAndTextWidget(icon: Icons.circle_sharp, 
                                  text: "Normal", 
                                  iconColor: Color(0xFFFFB74D)),

                                IconAndTextWidget(icon: Icons.location_on, 
                                  text: "1.7km", 
                                  iconColor: Color(0xFF80CBC4)),

                                IconAndTextWidget(icon: Icons.access_time_rounded, 
                                  text: "32min", 
                                  iconColor: Color(0xFFEF9A9A))
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
          ],
        );
      }


      // Zoom In and Zoom Out. And also scaling when we move it to left and right
      Widget _buildPageItem(int index) {
        Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4.identity();
        if (index==_currPageValue.floor()){
          var currScale = 1-(_currPageValue-index)*(1-_scaleFactor);
          var currTrans = _height*(1-currScale)/2;
          matrix=Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);

        }else if(index==_currPageValue.floor()+1){
          var currScale = _scaleFactor+(_currPageValue-index+1)*(1-_scaleFactor);
          var currTrans = _height*(1-currScale)/2;
          matrix=Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
          matrix=Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);

        }else if(index==_currPageValue.floor()-1){
          var currScale = 1-(_currPageValue-index)*(1-_scaleFactor);
          matrix=Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
          matrix=Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, currScale, 0);

        }else{
          var currScale=0.8;
          matrix=Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, _height*(1-_scaleFactor)/2, 1);

        }


        return Transform(
          transform: matrix,
          child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: Dimensions.pageViewContainer,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimensions.width10, right: Dimensions.width10), // Creates empty space between slides
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius30),
                color: Colors.black,
                //color: index.isEven ? Color(0xFF69c5df) : Color(0xFF9294cc),
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage("lib/assets/image/food1.png")
                )
            )
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container( // Thhe small widget in the main interface. It has a column with two rows below.
              height: Dimensions.pageViewTextContainer,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimensions.width30, right: Dimensions.width30, bottom: Dimensions.height30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  //Shadow property
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color(0xFFe8e8e8),
                      blurRadius: 5.0, //If it is 1, it is very very blurry
                      offset: Offset(0, 5)
                    ),
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      offset: Offset(-5, 0)
                    ),
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      offset: Offset(5, 0)
                    )
                  ]//It takes list of childeren
                  //color: index.isEven ? Color(0xFF69c5df) : Color(0xFF9294cc),
              ),
              child: AppColumn(text: "Turkish Side"),
            ),
          )
        ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

For example, the "Popular" text can not be printed. It only prints the first letter "P". The screenshot of the "Layout Explorer" is given below. What would be the best approach to fix it? Thanks in advance!

[image: flutter_layout_issue]